# How do I apply a style to all buttons of an Android application

Tags: android, button, stylesheet

I have a style applied to my whole application:

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application android:theme="@style/ApplicationStyle" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
```

And in my styles.xml:

```
 <style name="ApplicationStyle" parent="android:Theme">
  <item name="android:button">@style/CKButton</item>
 </style>
 <style name="CKButton" parent="android:style/Widget.Button">
  <item name="android:textSize">19sp</item>
  <item name="android:layout_margin">0dip</item>
  <item name="android:background">#ff0000</item>
 </style>
```

But the style doesn't get applied.

I'm sorry if I just used the false name in the `ApplicationStyle` - `Item`, but I have no clue where to look for the object names and simply assumed, that `android:button` applies to all buttons.

Comment: Please take a look at my answer on http://stackoverflow.com/a/26625931/1065835

Answer (score 216, accepted):

For Android styles, you reference the preset attributes that Android has laid out in [`R.attr`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html). In this case, it looks like you want to to reference [`android:buttonStyle`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#buttonStyle).  I think this would work:

```
<style name="ApplicationStyle" parent="android:Theme">
  <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/CKButton</item>
</style>
```

Comment: God, I was looking for such functionality for ages. Got no idea why buttons' textColor does not follow main theme's textColor property. Thanks much!

Comment: any one no how to do this for spinner?

Comment: Just one note: if the CKButton style does not inherit @android:style/Widget.Button, the button will stop working.

Comment: what is difference between `parent="android:Widget.Button"` and `parent=@android:style/Widget.Button`?

Comment: Why layout editor do not preview changes as per the button style set in the theme

Answer (score 26):

For Material components theme it would be like this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

    <item name="materialButtonStyle">@style/AppTheme.Button</item>
</style>
```