# Set the RBG value of android.R.styleable.Theme_textColorDim

Tags: android

Can you please tell me how can I set the RBG value of android.R.styleable.Theme_textColorDim
for my android application?

Thank you.

I have added this styles.xml file in my project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
resources>
<style name="ApplicationStyle" parent="android:Theme">
  <item name="android:textColorDim">#00ff00</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

But when I compile it, I get this error:

> res/values/styles.xml:19: error:
>   Error: No resource found that matches
>   the given name: attr
>   'android:textColorDim'.

So how can I set the textColorDim?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [theme](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html) that overrides one of the `textColorXX` attributes in [android.R.attr](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/R.attr.html), and then apply that theme to your activity or even the entire application.

These links may prove to be helpful:

- http://blog.androgames.net/40/custom-button-style-and-theme/
- [How do I apply a style to all buttons of an Android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2410836/how-do-i-apply-a-style-to-all-buttons-of-an-android-application)