# How to apply an style to all ImageButtons in Android?

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-button

I have the following style in my application.

```
  <style name="BtnPressed">
      <item name="android:background">@drawable/btn_default</item>
  </style>
```

Now I want to apply that to all the `ImageButtons` in my application. I tried to use the solution mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2410836/how-do-i-apply-a-style-to-all-buttons-of-an-android-application) but it did not work. I'm using API-7.

Comment: Did you take a look at the question portion of that link as well? That user has it set up correctly; you have to create a whole theme using a `<style>` tag with a `parent="android:Theme"`, and you need to have your `<application>` tag set up to use that theme in your manifest.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change your BtnPressed style to this:

```
<style name="BtnPressedStyle" parent="Widget.ImageButton">
  <item name="android:background">@drawable/btn_default</item>
</style>
```

Define an application-wide theme/style:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="android:Theme">
   <item name="android:imageButtonStyle">@style/BtnPressedStyle</item>
</style>
```

Then apply it to your application tag of the manifest:

```
<application theme="@style/MyTheme" ... />
```

Let me know if this works, I adapted it from my code that overrides application-wide button style, but ImageButton should work just as well.

Answer (score -5):

You can also spend about 5 minutes in your IDE (notepad++ will do) and search and replace ImageView on xmls , and a little snippet for image views generated in code. I don't think it's so wrong, and will help you to maintain the app.

Comment: That wouldn't be a very efficient way of doing it.

Comment: But bad practice. DRY - Don't Repeat Yourself.