# Meaning of 'android:' prefix within attribute value (e.g. "android:imageButtonStyle")

Tags: android

I want to style all my ImageButtons in a theme. After searching for quite some time I found the solution to my problem. But I don't know why it works like it does.

My main layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher_foreground" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This is my original **theme that didn't work**. It styles my TextView but ignores the ImageButton. The result is shown in the screenshot below.

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:imageButtonStyle">@style/redBackground</item>
        <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/redBackground</item>
    </style>

    <style name="redBackground">
        <item name="android:background">#FF0000</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

[image]

And here's the **theme that works**:

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="imageButtonStyle">@style/redBackground</item>
        <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/redBackground</item>
    </style>

    <style name="redBackground">
        <item name="android:background">#FF0000</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

[image]

The only difference is the missing 'android:' prefix in front of the 'imageButtonStyle' attribute.

So my questions are:

- What is the difference between imageButtonStyle and android:imageButtonStyle?
- Why does android:textViewStyle work but not android:imageButtonStyle? They are both defined the plattforms 'attrs.xml'.
- Why is there no textViewStyle (without android prefix)? Removing the prefix yields an error.
- Where are the attributes defined that have no prefix? Apparently not in the plattforms 'attrs.xml'.
- Where can I find proper documentation for the whole style stuff? Of course I halve already read the respective Google docs (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/themes.html). But still i have basic questions like this one.

Interestingly, it seems like the 'android:imageButtonStyle' version has worked some years ago: [How to apply an style to all ImageButtons in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11380978/how-to-apply-an-style-to-all-imagebuttons-in-android). I haven't tested that myself, though.

And here's the post that proposed removing the android prefix. Including unanswered comments that ask why it works: [buttonStyle not working for 22.1.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29882292/buttonstyle-not-working-for-22-1-1)

Answer (score 0):

android tag that you use is used for attribute coming from Android SDK.

app tag is used if you are using the support library.app is just a namespace for any custom parameters for a custom View.

This can be anything but if you see the root element there's probably a line xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" that assigns the namespace

You may also see other namespaces if you are using custom views (of your own or form a library).

Comment: The posted code is complete. I didn't leave out any namespace declarations. But that leads me to the next question: Why do I apply an AppCompat attribute (srcCompat) although I didn't use the support libraries ImageButton? I was never really aware of that..

Comment: Ok, I did some research about the support libraries layout inflater in general that answers my question in my comment but unfortunately not my original ones.

Answer (score 0):

In case that anyone else stumbles across the question: I've found the answer in this Droidcon talk: https://youtu.be/Jr8hJdVGHAk?t=21m12s

The topic is handled in a minute starting at 21:12.

As I understand it, specifying no namespace results in the global namespace being searched which seems to include the support libraries attributes. And indeed both, the [SDK's R.attr](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#imageButtonStyle) as well as the [support library's R.attr](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/appcompat/R.attr.html#imageButtonStyle) define the `imageButtonStyle` attribute (with slightly different descriptions). However, the support library does not define a `textViewStyle` attribute. So that explains why you can't omit it's `android:` prefix.

To answer my last question concerning the documentation: Despite the Google guide and the R.attr classes' documentation, the video mentioned above and this Google I/O talk are quite informative: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TIHXGwRTMWI

So the only question that is left open is why the SDK's `imageButtonStyle` does not work.

Comment: "why the SDK's `imageButtonStyle` does not work" - You're apparently in an `AppCompatActivity`, which automatically creates the `AppCompat` versions of certain SDK `View`s if they're found in the layout. `ImageButton` is one of those that is "upgraded", and `AppCompatImageButton` will use the `imageButtonStyle` attribute in the app's namespace.