# How to apply style to all buttons in Android application?

Tags: android, button, styles

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2410938/1742204)
doesn't work, because there is no `buttonStyle` item name. It has only `button`.

My example:

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black">
        <item name="android:button">@style/ThemeButton</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ThemeButton" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/button</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

But this doesn't work either.

Comment: Yes, there is buttonStyle item. Are you sure that you are using Theme.Black in your application?

Comment: Yes. But there no buttonStyle, see my screen: http://s43.radikal.ru/i100/1302/f1/012f48561ebd.png

Comment: It doesn't matter that eclipse is not showing it. It is there, try to type it and run your application.

Comment: Ok, when I use it force it works. Thanks...

Comment: It's not forcing it. Eclipse isn't perfect sometimes :)

Answer (score 6):

I override the button style for every theme when using different themes for different API levels. Consider the following example.

Your application's theme for API 14+ is a theme which derives from `android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar`.

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- API 14 theme customizations can go here. -->
</style>
```

`android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar` doesn't have its own `buttonStyle`, but its parent `Theme.Holo.Light` does. And the button style is the following:

```
<item name="buttonStyle">@style/Widget.Holo.Light.Button</item>
```

But your application's theme for API 21 derives from `android:Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar`

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- API 21 theme customizations can go here. -->
</style>
```

The button style of `android:Theme.Material.Light` is the following:

```
<item name="buttonStyle">@style/Widget.Material.Light.Button</item>
```

`Widget.Button` is a grandfather of `Widget.Holo.Light.Button` and `Widget.Material.Light.Button` I mentioned above. So if you derive from `Widget.Button` in your application, you will lose the customizations Google engineers provided for `Widget.Material.Light.Button` and `Widget.Holo.Light.Button`.

I recorded a few examples to demonstrate this.

**Android button style. Widget.Button for all API levels.**

The old-fashioned button for all API levels
http://youtu.be/hKWUFgvw-Gs

styles.xml in the folder *values* looks like this:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">

    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/Button</item>
</style>

<style name="Button" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button"></style>
```

**Every button style derives from the button style of its theme.**

The button has the Material animation http://youtu.be/8Wp1TWjjha0

styles.xml in the folder *values-v21* looks like this:

```
<resources>

    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- API 14 theme customizations can go here. -->
    </style>

    <style name="BaseButton" parent="@android:style/Widget.Material.Light.Button"></style>

</resources>
```

styles.xml in the folder *values-v14* looks like this:

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    </style>

    <style name="BaseButton" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Button"></style>

</resources>
```

styles.xml in the folder *values* looks like this:

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light"></style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/Button</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Button" parent="@style/BaseButton">
        <item name="android:text">Lorem Ipsum</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

[Material Design for Android 5.0 (API level 21)](https://developer.android.com/design/material/index.html)

[How to record your screen on Android 4.4.4](http://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-record-your-screen-on-android-4-4-kitkat/)

[Video bitrates](http://help.encoding.com/knowledge-base/article/understanding-bitrates-in-video-files/)

Comment: why does this stop working with API level 16? I can't set a style for all buttons

Comment: @Michail, can you please post your code? On Github, for example