# Change the default onPress color in Android

Tags: android, styles, android-actionbar, mapfragment

On my Galaxy S3, by default when buttons are pressed their backgrounds take on a light blue color. Is there a way to change this color?

I am aware of State List Drawables, and I've been able to use them to do this in certain situations. However, there are some things that still use this default color that I would like to change. For instance:

- The home button in the Action Bar still uses the light blue color when it's pressed
- The display buttons in a MapFragment (zoom in, zoom out, my location, etc.) still use the light blue color

If anyone knows how to change this color in general across the entire app, or even for just these two instances, that would be very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: You need to override the theme and provide your own implementations and style, it'll effect the look and feel in your entire app. Have a look here: [How do I apply a style to all buttons of an Android application](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2410938/593709)

Comment: Unfortunately that is not working. I have custom styles defined for all buttons (as in, it is being applied to the android:buttonStyle attribute), and when I add a plain button to an activity I see that styles are definitely working. However, they are not being applied to either the Action Bar home button or the MapFragment display buttons. Do you have any idea how to extend the styles to those buttons?