# Android application style

Tags: android, css, button, styles

I would like to set a specific style for the whole application.

I added the style in the androidmanifest.xml, and I defined the style as follow:

```
   <style name="myStyle">
        <item name="android:background">#000000</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
    </style>
```

This style changes the background and the textcolor for the whole application, though I would like to change also the text color of the buttons:  this sentence works when defining a button but I would like to add it to the style of the application

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

```
   <style name="myStyle" parent="android:Theme">
   <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/Your button style</item>
   </style>
```

source:[How do I apply a style to all buttons of an Android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2410836/how-do-i-apply-a-style-to-all-buttons-of-an-android-application)