# Changing Button Text color in theme for >= Android 4.2

Tags: android, android-layout, android-theme

I've been searching but still am unable to find a way.

How does one change all text button colors (without modifying the `android:textColor` of other widgets in a scheme?

NB: Does not work

```
 <!-- Base application theme. -->
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">#1bbc9b</item>
    <!--<item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>-->
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/AppTheme.MyButton</item>
  </style>

  <style name="AppTheme.MyButton" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
  </style>
```

**UPDATE: Fix for just altering button color, not entire button style**

Comment: Please check this link , it may helpful to you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2410836/how-do-i-apply-a-style-to-all-buttons-of-an-android-application

Comment: Hello @Amee, still does not work.. It is using AppCompat 7.22.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me.  In the `values/styles.xml`, configure:

```
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">#fcfc00</item>
    <!-- more stuff here -->
  </style>
```