# Android button style for all buttons not working on device

Tags: android

I tried to make a custom button style for all my buttons in my app like in this [question/solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2410836/how-do-i-apply-a-style-to-all-buttons-of-an-android-application). I want to do it like that because I dont want to add:

```
android:style="@style/MyButtonStyle"
```

to every button

My current code.

**styles.xml**

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/MyButtonStyle</item>
</style>

<!-- Button style. -->
<style name="MyButtonStyle" parent="android:style/Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/ColorTextIcons</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/ColorAccent</item>
</style>
```

**Manifest**

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

In the preview in android studio it looks good, however when I run the app i get a default button style. As far as I know its the same as the accepted answer with 120 upvotes.

What is wrong with the code and why is it showing different in android studio?

**Preview in android studio.**

[image]

**My device (s5 mini android 4.4.2)**

[image]
**NOTE** I dont apply any different styles/themes to the activitys

Answer (score 0):

Try one among these:

Apply theme to activity/application:

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

Apply style to button:

```
style="@style/MyButtonStyle"
```

If you are using compat library you can get errors depending on your android version:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/MyButtonStyle</item>
    <item name="buttonStyle">@style/MyButtonStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyButtonStyle" parent="android:style/Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/ColorTextIcons</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/ColorAccent</item>
    <item name="textColor">@color/ColorTextIcons</item>
    <item name="background">@color/ColorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Tried it not chaning anything for me.

Comment: I've edited my answer. I hope this would help you more than the previous. If not, try removing parent tag.

Comment: android:style="@style/MyButtonStyle" works but as i posted in the question, I don't want to add a style to every single button but want a default style.

Comment: Last chance, I've edited my answer again. Sorry I can't check my answers because I don't have my laptop available.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be

```
<style name="MyButtonStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">
```

and

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

With the `@android` and the `@style`.

Comment: Tried it, no differences