# How to change default button style in Android?

Tags: android

I want to change the style of the `Button`. And I add the style in `style.xml` then set the `@style/BaseButton` to every `Button`.
Is there any way can do it better? Can I just set the theme to change all `Button` or other views?
I know that I can add the theme to the `style.xml` but unfortunately, if I set the attributes like `@android:background` to the `Button`, other views' backgrounds are set too.

So here are what I need:

- Set the style in only one(or some) place(s). No need to set style in
  every layout and every `<Button />`.
- Only the `Button` is    influenced while other views stay where they
  are.
- Can be changed easily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow below steps

1. Create an XML file that represents the button states

   ```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
    android:state_enabled="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/button_disabled" />
   <item
   android:state_pressed="true"
   android:state_enabled="true"
   android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed" />
   <item
   android:state_focused="true"
   android:state_enabled="true"
   android:drawable="@drawable/button_focused" />
   <item
   android:state_enabled="true"
   android:drawable="@drawable/button_enabled" />
   </selector>
   ```
2. Create an XML file that represents each button state

   First button shape is for the enabled button state.

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

   <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  android:shape="rectangle">
   <gradient
   android:startColor="#00CCFF"
   android:centerColor="#0000CC"
   android:endColor="#00CCFF"
   android:angle="90"/>
   <padding android:left="7dp"
   android:top="7dp"
   android:right="7dp"
   android:bottom="7dp" />
   <stroke
   android:width="2dip"
   android:color="#FFFFFF" />
   <corners android:radius= "8dp" />
   </shape>
   ```

   Second button shape is for the focused button state.

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

   <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
   <gradient
   android:startColor="#F7D358"
   android:centerColor="#DF7401"
   android:endColor="#F7D358"
   android:angle="90"/>
   <padding android:left="7dp"
   android:top="7dp"
   android:right="7dp"
   android:bottom="7dp" />
   <stroke
   android:width="2dip"
   android:color="#FFFFFF" />
   <corners android:radius= "8dp" />
   </shape>
   ```

   Third button shape is for the pressed button state.

   ```
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

     <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
     android:startColor="#0000CC"
     android:centerColor="#00CCFF"
     android:endColor="#0000CC"
     android:angle="90"/>
     <padding android:left="7dp"
     android:top="7dp"
     android:right="7dp"
     android:bottom="7dp" />
     <stroke
     android:width="2dip"
     android:color="#FFFFFF" />
     <corners android:radius= "8dp" />
     </shape>
   ```

   And finally, Fourth button shape is for the disabled button state.

   ```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

   <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
   <gradient
   android:startColor="#F2F2F2"
   android:centerColor="#A4A4A4"
   android:endColor="#F2F2F2"
   android:angle="90"/>
   <padding android:left="7dp"
   android:top="7dp"
   android:right="7dp"
   android:bottom="7dp" />
   <stroke
   android:width="2dip"
   android:color="#FFFFFF" />
   <corners android:radius= "8dp" />
   </shape>
   ```
3. Create an XML file that represents the button style

   ```
   <resources>
   <style name="button" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">
   <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical|center_horizontal</item>
   <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFFFF</item>
   <item name="android:shadowColor">#FF000000</item>
   <item name="android:shadowDx">0</item>
   <item name="android:shadowDy">-1</item>
   <item name="android:shadowRadius">0.2</item>
   <item name="android:textSize">16dip</item>
   <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
   <item name="android:background">@drawable/button</item>
   <item name="android:focusable">true</item>
   <item name="android:clickable">true</item>
   </style>
   ```
4. Create an XML with your own custom application theme .`themes.xml` below

   ```
   <resources>
   <style name="YourApplicationTheme" parent="android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
   <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/button</item>
   </style>
   </resources>
   ```

Now, you can create buttons on your application with the new style

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
<style name="ApplicationStyle" parent="android:Theme">
  <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/CKButton</item>
</style>
```

Linked from:
[How do I apply a style to all buttons of an Android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2410836/how-do-i-apply-a-style-to-all-buttons-of-an-android-application)

Comment: later on add some explanation also. Because your answer will be invalid if the link is broken. right? however up voted.good luck @Busi_rusi