# Android Certification. Apply a custom style to a group of common widgets. How can we do that?

Tags: android

Preparing for Android Associate Developers certification. How ever I don't understand this question. Different widgets will be in different apps or same apps. What they mean by that? How to achieve it?

Comment: I think this is what you want https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2410836/how-do-i-apply-a-style-to-all-buttons-of-an-android-application